Implement `copyWith` for a Generic class that has a field that is a generic function
Consider the following class:
@immutable
class Foo<T, R> {
  const Foo({
    required this.bar,
  });

  final R Function(T data) bar;

  Foo copyWith({
    R Function(T data)? bar,
  }) {
    return Foo(
      bar: bar ?? this.bar,
    );
  }
}

In the above class, the line bar: bar ?? this.bar results in the diagnostic message:

The argument type 'R Function(T)' can't be assigned to the parameter
type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'.

How should a copyWith method be implemented for generic function field in an immutable generic class?

Your problem is that your copyWith implementation is declared to return a Foo, but that is shorthand for Foo<dynamic, dynamic>.  Type inference then flows top-down to the returned expression, causing Foo(bar: bar ?? this.bar) to be inferred as constructing a Foo<dynamic, dynamic> instead of as constructing a Foo<T, R> (which otherwise would happen from bottom-up type inference).
You therefore should fix the return type:
  Foo<T, R> copyWith({
    R Function(T data)? bar,
  }) {
    return Foo(
      bar: bar ?? this.bar,
    );
  }

Note that you could force bottom-up inference by doing:
  // Probably not what you want!
  Foo copyWith({
    R Function(T data)? bar,
  }) {
    var copy = Foo(
      bar: bar ?? this.bar,
    );
    return copy;
  }

and that also would avoid the static type error, but it would end up implicitly casting a Foo<T, R> to Foo<dynamic, dynamic>, which probably isn't what you want.
I strongly recommend enabling strict-raw-types in your analysis_options.yaml file to catch cases where dynamic is implicitly used when generic type parameters are accidentally omitted.

Thank you for bringing the strict-raw-types analysis option to my attention.
